# How do I stop the code completely as soon as a certain thing is done?

Tags: python, while-loop

I've already ruled out `os.exit`, `sys.exit()`, `raise SystemExit(0)`, `quit`, and `exit()`.

I want to completely stop once one of my multiple while conditions are fulfilled.

```
while x:
    #do something
    #for loop
    #if a:
        #do something
        print "Game over"
        os.exit
    #elif b:
        #do something
        print "Game over"
        os.exit
    break

while y:
    #(...same form as the previous one^)

#get user input for the next turn

#while 1
#...
#while n
```

When I play the game, and the game over message is printed on to the screen, it still asks for the user input despite being told to stop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: it would be appropriate to use an `else if` where by the `while` loop will be inside the `elif` in this case it will break automatically.

Comment: Why cant you use `sys.exit()`?

Comment: Why have you "ruled out" those methods?

Comment: It sounds like you just forgot the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how sys.exit() should work. Sys.exit() should work if you import it and reach it. Maybe more troubleshooting information would be helpful? This works for python and python3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

while 1==1:
    print("This will print")

    if 2==2:
        print("This will also print")
        sys.exit()

    print("This will not print")
print("This will not print")
```

This is my terminal output:

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro:Desktop mw$ ./stupid.py 
This will print
This will also print
```

edit.

As @goosfraba said, sys.exit(0) would probably be best practice. [The link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) provided says no argument can have undefined behavior. Another argument like 1 or "This is an error message" would also work.

Comment: Solved! Thank you. Nice file name by the way.

Answer (score 0):

With these small alterations, I managed to make this work:

```
import os

while True:
    #do something
    #for loop
    if False:
        #do something
        print "Game over A"
        os._exit(0)
    elif True:
        #do something
        print "Game over B"
        os._exit(0)
    break

print "Not over"
```

Output:

```
Game over B
```

Note the lack of the **Not over** output.
Perhaps `_exit(<status>)` is what you need?

Comment: While that technically works, so should the regular `sys.exit`. There are legitimate uses of `os._exit`, but using it here seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Am sorry, I know one did down vote my response as it was similar to yours. The issue was I was still typing out my solution yet you had already posted yours. But if you look at the comments above, I did mention the use of `if else` statement

Comment: If you have a comment that pertains to your answer, please post it there, not here.  I'm not the person who down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
sys.exit(n)
```

Where the optional n is an integer with the exit status.

Please check: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html